# No valid serial ports for Arduino UNO on Mac

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, mac-os

**UPDATE:** The issue turned out to be with my work laptop. Our IT department has them configured in such a way that the assignment of serial ports is different somehow. When I plugged in on my personal Macbook Pro it all worked perfectly.

---

I just got my first Arduino. Its an UNO R3. I'm running OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) and the Arduino IDE 1.0.5

Under **Tools>Board** I have Arduino Uno selected

Under **Tools>Serial** Port my options are:

- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Serial-1
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Serial-1
- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Serial-2
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Serial-2
- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem
- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync

I've tried all of them, but when I try to upload a sketch it fails. Most give the following error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

The two "modem" options return this message:

```
Serial port '/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem' already in use. Try quitting any programs that may be using it.
```

I'm at a loss. None of these serial ports seems correct but there aren't any other options.

Also under **Tools>Programmer** which option should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with my work laptop. Our IT department has them configured in such a way that the assignment of serial ports is different somehow. When I plugged in on my personal Macbook Pro it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you hooked up your Arduino prior to pulling down the tools>Serial Port menu? I only see the port for my Arduino listed when it's actually connected and running. (And it's never one of the bluetooth ports.) I don't have my Arduino with me at the moment so I can't tell you exactly what it is.

Also note that on my MBP (running 10.9.4) I have to be sure to plug the USB cable into the CORRECT USB port. The other port maps to a different port in the list of serial ports.